# Does it make sense to connect Angular.js app directly to Dynamodb? Alternatives to remove backend in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, amazon-dynamodb

From my point of view, this could be a winner combination in order to reduce sysadmin / scale problems by removing the backend directly. Does it make sense to you? Is there an established solution to remove the backend in web apps with db access?

I've been looking out there but seems there's a few people using this combination directly although there's an AWS SDK in Javascript available... Is there a reason to not use this "direct" connection? Security reasons?

Comment: If you don't care about exposing your aws key publicly then yes you can do it right in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting ready to start a small project that will potentially do this. You should NOT embed your keys in the browser and you do not have to.

Please review the following [AWS JavaScript SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html) and pay attention to the Loading Credentials in the Client's Browser section.

Personally I plan on utilizing an S3 Upload and perhaps a DynamoDB connection. There is a new service called [AWS Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html) which is referenced in the above documentation which allows for simplifying a token vending machine to grant temp access to users to access your AWS service.  One of the recent updates of Cognito is the ability to use your own custom authentication service.